# Interface conversion of fields on equivalent structures

Tags: go

Is there a straightforward way to convert a struct where some fields are "generic" (`interface{}`) into another type which has the same field names but is "strongly-typed" (`int`, `string`, etc)?

Lets say that, given the definitions:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type GenericData struct {
    Hard int
    Soft interface{}
}

type Data struct {
    Hard int
    Soft int
}

type GenericDataGenerator func() GenericData

func generateGenericData() interface{} {
    return GenericData{1, 2}
}

func returnsGenericDataGenerator() interface{} {
    return generateGenericData
}
```

Does converting from `GenericData` to `Data` require explicitly casting all `interface{}` fields? Is there a more straightforwad way to do this?

```
func main() {
    gd := generateGenericData()
    fmt.Println(gd)
    fmt.Println(gd.(GenericData))

    // Doesn't work, but is straightforward
    // fmt.Println(gd.(Data))

    // Works, but is not straight forward
    fmt.Println(Data{gd.(GenericData).Hard, gd.(GenericData).Soft.(int)})


    genDataGenerator := returnsGenericDataGenerator()

    // Doesn't work, but is straightforward
    //genDataGenerator.(GenericDataGenerator)()

    // Works, but is not straight forward
    resp := genDataGenerator.(func() interface{})()
    fmt.Println(resp.(GenericData))
}
```

The code can be executed in:
https://play.golang.org/p/_UVBi5It1FY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a straightforward way to convert a struct where some fields are "generic" (interface{}) into another type which has the same field names but is "strongly-typed" (int, string, etc)?

No.

And this is obvious once you understand that `interface{}` is not some kind of "generic" or "arbitrary" type but a single, "strongly-type" type just like `string` or `int32`. The empty interface `interface{}` is a totally normal type just like a `uint16` or a `map[float32]bool` is. It is a interface type (in contrast to the other examples which are a numeric type and a map type) and its method set is the empty set. It is as strict or strongly typed as any of the other types.

The fact that you can assign any value to a variable of type `interface{}` does not mean that `interface{}` somehow means "any type". You can assign the values `3`, `-1234`and `435948` (to name a few) to a `int32`. This is allowed because the allowed value range of a `int32` contains these values (3, -1234, 435948). You can assign a value of type `func(int) string` to a variable of type `interface{}` because the allowed value range of `interface{}` contains `func(int)string`. This is a vacuous truth and not a "generic" one.